# Loading Spring context with specific classloader

Tags: spring, classloader

How can I go about loading a Spring context with my own `ClassLoader` instance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Many Spring Context Loader (for example [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html)
) are subclass of [DefaultResourceLoader](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/DefaultResourceLoader.html).

`DefaultResourceLoader` has a [constructor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/DefaultResourceLoader.html#DefaultResourceLoader%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29) where you can specify the Classloader and also has a [`setClassLoader`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/DefaultResourceLoader.html#setClassLoader%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29) method.

So it is your task to find a constructor of the Spring Context Loader you need, where you can specify the classloader, or just create it, and then use the set to set the classloader you want.

Answer (score 6):

```
    final ClassLoader properClassLoader = YourClass.class.getClassLoader();

    appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml") {

        protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader) {
            super.initBeanDefinitionReader(reader);
            reader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_NONE);
            reader.setBeanClassLoader(properClassLoader);
            setClassLoader(properClassLoader);
```

See here if you are doing this for OSGI purposes: [How do I use a Spring bean inside an OSGi bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039931/how-do-i-use-a-spring-bean-inside-an-osgi-bundle)

Comment: I also needed to do this to load the spring context in a Jenkins plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The `org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` class is here for you.

Comment: This class does not let you pass in the class loader.  This is not a correct answer.

Comment: The ClassPathXmlApplicationContext being a subclass of DefaultResourceLoader, it inherits the setClassloader method. So you can actually pass your class loader.

Comment: This is true, but you do not inherit constructors.  You can only use the ones declared on the class (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html)

Answer (score 0):

People who are using spring boot and wants to use custom classloader to create application context can do it like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
  
        
        SpringApplication app =
            new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        
        ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();

        YourClassLoaderObject yourClassLoaderObject = new YourClassLoaderObject();

        ((DefaultResourceLoader)resourceLoader).setClassLoader(yourClassLoaderObject);
                
        app.setResourceLoader(resourceLoader);
        
        context = app.run(args);
        
        
       
    }
    
}
```